# Xcode: How to select two different App Groups for two different targets pointing on two different team account (Enterprise & Company)

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I have two different targets, and I try to get two different groups to each targets. My goal is to have two different versions, one for the App Store, one for distribution. I installed the push notification that worked well until now for the Company version, but, as I created the enterprise provisionning, xcode refuse to put different groups for this two targets (**in the Capabilities/App Groups section**)

**Target Enterprise:**
[image: Target Enterprise]
[image]
**Target Company (for Apple Store)**
[image: Target Company (App Store)]
[image]

How to get this two targets with two different groups? (Xcode change me automatically for the target *GMP_app_ios*, if I change the group of the target *GMP_app_ios AppStore* and vice versa).

Comment: What are the values for the **Code Signing Entitlements** (under Build Settings) for each target?

Comment: When building an app for multiple environments, I'd suggest configuring it using `.xcconfig`s instead of creating multiple targets. Try checking out this post https://thoughtbot.com/blog/let-s-setup-your-ios-environments.

Comment: @BojanDimovski Good point, it is exaclty the same for both : GMP_app_ios/GMP_app_ios.entitlements   Is it the source of the problem?

Comment: Yes, you have two options, the first is a quick fix and would be to create a duplicate file and set it in the build settings. The other one, which needs a bit more work, but is better on the long run, is to migrate to `xcconfig`s.

Comment: @BojanDimovski Thank you for you answer, I will do it for now the quick solution, but I will put the second one for the long term.

Comment: I'll put it as an answer since it ultimately solves the problem.

Comment: Yep, I will validate it, I just did it, It works perfectly. I would never find this without your advice :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you have a duplicated target, the issue is that the second target uses the same entitlements file as the original one (check the official documentation for more [info](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AboutEntitlements.html)).

You can do a quick fix, which would be to duplicate the entitlements file and update the **Code Signing Entitlements** (`CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS`) value under **Build Settings**.

A long term solution would be to migrate the project to using `xcconfig` files, having a single target with different configuration pairs (`Debug` and `Release`) for each environment (**Enterprise** and **Company** in your case). A good starting point would be the [Let's Set Up Your iOS Environments](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/let-s-setup-your-ios-environments) blog post.

Also, note that the values in the entitlement files **must** correspond to the values in the App ID configuration on the developer portal.

Comment: Thanks for the link @bojan-dimovski .  I didn't realize potential of this xcconfig file.